# How to transpose a regression output with modelsummary package?

Tags: r, latex, regression, modelsummary

I JUST found out about this amazing R package, `modelsummary`.

It doesn't seem like it offers an ability to transpose regression outputs.

I know that you cannot do a tranposition within `kable-extra`, which is my go-to for ordinary table outputs in R. Since `modelsummary` relies on `kable-extra` for post-processing, I'm wondering if this is possible. Has anyone else figured it out?

Ideally I'd like to preserve the stars of my regression output.
This is available in [STATA](http://repec.org/bocode/e/estout/advanced.html#advanced907) (below):

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: How about `t(modelsummary(mod, output="huxtable"))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flip the order of the terms in the `group` argument formula.  [See documentation here](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/reference/modelsummary.html) and also [here for many examples.](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html#group)

```r
library(modelsummary)

mod <- list(
  lm(mpg ~ hp, mtcars),
  lm(mpg ~ hp + drat, mtcars))

modelsummary(mod, group = model ~ term)
```

|  | (Intercept) | hp | drat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Model 1 | 30.099 | -0.068 |  |
|  | (1.634) | (0.010) |  |
| Model 2 | 10.790 | -0.052 | 4.698 |
|  | (5.078) | (0.009) | (1.192) |

The main problem with this strategy is that there is not (yet) an automatic way to append goodness of fit statistics. So you would probably have to rig something up by creating a `data.frame` and feeding it to the `add_columns` argument. For example:

```r
N <- sapply(mod, function(x) get_gof(x)$nobs)
N <- data.frame(N = c(N[1], "", N[2], ""))
modelsummary(mod,
             group = model ~ term,
             add_columns = N,
             align = "lcccc")
```

|  | (Intercept) | hp | drat | N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Model 1 | 30.099 | -0.068 |  | 32 |
|  | (1.634) | (0.010) |  |  |
| Model 2 | 10.790 | -0.052 | 4.698 | 32 |
|  | (5.078) | (0.009) | (1.192) |  |

If you have ideas about the best default behavior for goodness of fit statistics, please file a feature request on Github.